# Multi Threaded TCP Server Echo back to all clients

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp, server

i have been working on a TCP NAT Punch Through server/Client chat room setup. i have successfully set it up in UDP and now i want to do the same thing for TCP as i'm a little rough on my sockets atm.

any ways the clients can connect fine and chat and receive echo's but depending on the amount of connections it will echo back to the same client who sent the message based on the amount of clients connected. e.g 3 clients conencted client2 sends a ping it echos back to client 2, 3 times.  it should be going through a loop of IPEndPoint List of all connected users and doing a sock.SendTo(data,data.Length,clients[i]);

but its echoing back to the client who sent the message. no idea what ive done wrong, but i thought i had done it all right. but this is bothering me. some guidance on what i have done wrong would be much appreciated.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create a socket
        //create a end point to listen on
        //bind
        //listen
        //accept the socket on a new socket
        //receive
        //store the connection in a list
        //ping back on their socket
        //go back to listening state

        Console.Title = " TCP NAT PT Server";

        StartServer();
    }

    private static void StartServer()
    {
        Thread ListenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
        ListenThread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("ListenThread: " + ListenThread.ThreadState);
    }

    private static void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            server.Bind(ep);
            server.Listen(0);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket handler = server.Accept();

                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientCommunication));
                clientThread.Start((object)handler);
                Console.WriteLine("ReceiveThread: " + clientThread.ThreadState);

                string rstr = handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                string[] rdata = rstr.Split(':');

                IPEndPoint rep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(rdata[0]), int.Parse(rdata[1]));
                clients.Add(rep);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void HandleClientCommunication(object Client)
    {
        Socket sock = (Socket)Client;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        string str = string.Empty;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                int rec = sock.Receive(data, SocketFlags.None);
                Array.Resize(ref data, rec);
                str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                Console.WriteLine(sock.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " >> " + str);

                //Console.WriteLine(clients.Count);
                //Console.WriteLine(clients[0].Address + ":" + clients[0].Port);

                string temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
                temp = "Echo: " + temp;
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(temp);
                Console.WriteLine("Data.Length: " + temp.Length);

                for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
                {
                    sock.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, clients[i]);
                    //sock.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                }

                data = new byte[1024];
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //socket error
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

```
 sock.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, clients[i]);
```

according to [SendTo method doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/beez6ewa(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> If you are using a connection-oriented protocol, you must first
>   establish a remote host connection by calling the Connect method or
>   accept an incoming connection request using the Accept method

You are using a socket connected to Endpoint A to send bytes to Endpoint B through TCP which wouldn't work actually.

So instead of keeping endpoints in the clients, keep a list of sockets in the listen method :

```
while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket handler = server.Accept();

                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientCommunication));
                clientThread.Start((object)handler);
                Console.WriteLine("ReceiveThread: " + clientThread.ThreadState);

                clients.Add(handler);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

and change the loop for sending messages to this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
{
    clients[i].Send(data);
}
```

Just a heads up : To avoid errors you need to remove items from the **clients** list once the client socket gets close.

Comment: funny enough i did exactly that an hour after laying in bed thinking what i had done wrong, and got it working in about 30 seconds. thanks for the help also. at least others will be able to get some use from it, i would up vote but i am unable to =/

Comment: Haha, happens sometimes, especially when you need to go to bed :))